# TH2D object to NumPy with bin labels

Tags: python, root-framework, uproot

I have a 2D correlation matrix between nuisance parameters that are used in a likelihood fit. I would like to translate this to NumPy to use with other vis libraries.
The problem is `TH2D.edges` returns the bin index and I need the bin label, i.e. which bin is which nuisance parameter. The `TH2D` object has the following members:

```
['fName',
 'fTitle',
 'fLineColor',
 'fLineStyle',
 'fLineWidth',
 'fFillColor',
 'fFillStyle',
 'fMarkerColor',
 'fMarkerStyle',
 'fMarkerSize',
 'fNcells',
 'fXaxis',
 'fYaxis',
 'fZaxis',
 'fBarOffset',
 'fBarWidth',
 'fEntries',
 'fTsumw',
 'fTsumw2',
 'fTsumwx',
 'fTsumwx2',
 'fMaximum',
 'fMinimum',
 'fNormFactor',
 'fContour',
 'fSumw2',
 'fOption',
 'fFunctions',
 'fBufferSize',
 'fBuffer',
 'fBinStatErrOpt',
 'fStatOverflows',
 'fScalefactor',
 'fTsumwy',
 'fTsumwy2',
 'fTsumwxy']
```

Is it possible to extract the bin label for each index?

Answer (score 1):

[TH2](https://uproot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/uproot.behaviors.TH2.TH2.html#) has an [axes tuple](https://uproot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/uproot.behaviors.TH2.TH2.html#axes) and an [axis method](https://uproot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/uproot.behaviors.TH2.TH2.html#axis) for getting each of its two [TAxis](https://uproot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/uproot.behaviors.TAxis.TAxis.html) objects.

From there, [TAxis](https://uproot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/uproot.behaviors.TAxis.TAxis.html) has a [labels method](https://uproot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/uproot.behaviors.TAxis.TAxis.html#labels) to extract the labels.

You didn't see it in the list of `TH2D` data members because it's in the `fXaxis` and `fYaxis`.